# Delete subscription returns 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I create one subscription in Microsoft Graph.

When I list the existing subscriptions (`GET /v1.0/subscriptions`),  the subscription with the id `X` is returned.

When I Delete the subscription (`DEL /v1.0/subscriptions/X`), I get an `HTTP 404` error with the following content:

```
"error": {
  "code": "ExtensionError",
  "message": "Operation: Delete; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound;    
              Reason: The subscription with Id '[an internal id]' is not found.]"
}
```

I noticed this behavior on 03/25/2019 but the API had been working since January.

Comment: What resources are subscribing to? Does this happen with any resource or subscription or just a couple of them?

Comment: I'm subscribing for email resources. Yes this happens for all subscriptions. I'm surprized because this feature worked well for months...